# Can I authenticate service client using K8S ServiceAccount in service-service call case without enabling Istio mTLS?

Tags: istio

Using the K8S ServiceAccount to authenticate service in Istio is quite interesting. Does it mean that we have to enable mTLS in order to use this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Istio represents security concepts with two separate methods for identification and traffic management actions:  [Authentication](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/security/#authentication) and [Authorization](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/security/#authorization). However, as every security infrastructure, Istio mesh requires to define the [Identity](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/security/#istio-identity) in front of the target service in order to obtain decision from underlying Authentication policies how the transport and service-to-service authentication should be established initially by [Pilot](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/what-is-istio/#pilot); Authorization policy can be used to enable Role-based Access Control ([RBAC](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/authorization/istio.rbac.v1alpha1/)) mechanism within entire namespace, service-level and method-level access control within objects along Istio mesh inside [Mixer](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/what-is-istio/#mixer).

Mutual [TLS](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/security/#mutual-tls-authentication) authentication is the secure way for service-to-service communication through Envoy [proxy](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/) within a particular Istio mesh object where Envoy [sidecar](https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/additional-setup/sidecar-injection/) is enabled; therefore [Citadel](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/what-is-istio/#citadel) creates TLS certificate inventory and enforce policy rules.

You might be able to launch mTLS authenication [globally](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/security/authn-policy/#globally-enabling-istio-mutual-tls) or either via manual and automatic sidecar [injection](https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/additional-setup/sidecar-injection/#injection).

Authentication policy propagates its rules on the client side within [Destination rules](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/traffic-management/#rule-destinations), therefore you may choose `trafficPolicy:` TLS mode enabled: `mode: ISTIO_MUTUAL` or disabled:

```
trafficPolicy:
   tls:
     mode: DISABLE
```

I encourage you to find some related information about ISTIO security model with the relevant practical examples [here](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/security/).